# Get min and max value from a multiple rows events

Tags: sql

I am having a table with following structure:

```
ID      TIME_UNIX     STATUS      TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS
1       1416234308      1         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
1       1416234313      0         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
1       1416234319      1         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
1       1416234337      0         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
2       1416319268      1         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))  
2       1416319280      0         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
2       1416319631      1         (dateadd(second,[time],'19700101'))
```

Value Descriptions

```
ID is the identifier of the object who does the insert
TIME_UNIX is when it happened
Status can be 1 or 0 (enable/disable)
TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS is just a friendly view of TIME_UNIX column
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to generate a view to show me for each object the min and max hours of each event, meaning, first enable and last disable for a day by object

```
ID    FIRST_ENABLE_TIME    LAST_DISABLE_TIME    DDMMYYY
1     1416234308           1416234337           17Nov2014
2     1416319268           1416319280           17Nov2014
```

Have been trying many inner joins, views and so far no luck...

Any body can help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN TIME_UNIX ELSE NULL END) AS FIRST_ENABLE_TIME, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN TIME_UNIX ELSE NULL END) AS LAST_DISABLE_TIME,
    TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS AS DDMMYYY
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS
```

Comment: Don't you need to group by the day, not the time?

Comment: Hi,
Executed but brings only data on 1 column min or max. 
604142   1415962295 NULL 2014-11-14 08:51:35.000
604081   1415962345     NULL    2014-11-14 08:52:25.000

Comment: Nice,@StevieG
I modified the group by and select to
convert(varchar(10),TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS,103) AS DDMMYYY
FROM login
GROUP BY ID, convert(varchar(10),TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS,103)
Seems to be working, will validate the datas. 
Thanks @Dan

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN TIME_UNIX ELSE NULL END) AS FIRST_ENABLE_TIME, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN TIME_UNIX ELSE NULL END) AS LAST_DISABLE_TIME,
    convert(varchar(10),TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS,103) AS DDMMYYY FROM
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, convert(varchar(10),TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS,103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, 
       (SELECT MIN(TIME_UNIX) 
        FROM table 
        WHERE status = 1) AS FIRST_ENABLE_TIME, 
       (SELECT MAX(TIME_UNIX)
        FROM table 
        WHERE status = 0) AS LAST_DISABLE_TIME, 
       TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS AS DDMMYYY
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS
```

Comment: This does not take into account that FIRST_ENABLE_TIME should only consider records where STATUS = 1, and LAST_DISABLE_TIME where STATUS = 0.

Comment: This does the min and max across all records, not by day?

Comment: Executing this query bring the Column 'login.TIME_DDMMYY_HHMMSS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.